# Internet Explorer poor gif quality / rendering

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, animation, gif

I am trying to solve a problem with internet explorer 10. I made a gif animation in photoshop (its only 1mb) and it works in all browsers well, except, Well take a guess... internet explorer. It looks like there is a pixel delay or rendering problem.

Gif animations of other websites doesn't have the problem. I also tried all kinds off different gif formats. Anyone any ideas?

I used the html img element to display

```
 <img src="database.gif" id="myVideo">
```

here is printscreen of my pc screen in IE10

[image]

This is the gif file (Open this page in IE)

[image]

Comment: Is your GIF special? E.g. huge file size, width, height, frame-rate, etc.?
Also: might be useful if you could upload the file/create a fiddle/whatever.

Comment: Works fine in IE 11, and in IE 10 mode (from IE 11).

Comment: I see the problem too in IE10. Have you tried setting your gif software so that the full image is stored for every frame, not just the pixels that have changed?

Comment: Also, why does the gif contain all the whitespace and the text and button, instead of just the animation?

Comment: @m69 oh it's needed for my portfolio. Anyways I don't know how to store full images in photoshop. Maybe it does already. Any ideas how to find out?

Comment: I don't think storing full images is an option if the whole thing has to be 1920x1080 pixels, because the file size would probably be huge. But if you want to try, in CS4 I see an "Optimize Animation" menu with the options "Bounding Box" and "Redundant Pixel Removal". Try unchecking these.

Comment: Btw, if I load the gif in IE10 and display it at its original resolution, the problem is gone; it's only when I zoom in or out that the problem occurs.

Comment: @m69 Alrighty Thanks for the response and effort. I am going to try that later!